# Как повернуть два треугольника, чтобы их вершины лежали максимально близко?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Допустим имеется два разных треугольника с общим центром и имеется задача повернуть один треугольник так, что бы его вершины лежали максимально близко к вершинам другого треугольника.

У меня есть идея только того, что чтобы найти новые координаты фигуры, нужно минимизировать расстояния между вершинами первого треугольника и второго (т.е. взять производную и приравнять нулю), однако как действовать дальше не знаю ..

Comment: Критерием должно быть ОДНО число. Расстояния между тремя парами точек на одно число тянут слабо... так что сначала формулируй критерий (например, минимальная сумма квадратов может подойти...). А затем в полярной системе координат (в ней крутить проще) строишь аналитически эту сумму квадратов и ищешь корни первой производной - в общем, задача вполне стандартная.

Comment: @Akina Задача не так стандартна, как может показаться. Один из вопросов, на который придется ответить - какие вершины двух треугольников считать парными, и следует ли рассматривать такие пары. А полярные координаты или декартовы - это вообще никакого значения не имеет.

Comment: Нельзя ли брать в качестве такого скаляра сумму всех всех комбинаций расстояний?

Comment: Я пробовал данным способом (нахождение корней производных) однако я получаю что координаты одного вектора должны быть точно такими же что и координаты второго (то есть изменяется длина вектора, что нежелательно в моей задаче) и это осевидно поскольку должен быть констрейн на длину

Comment: *Один из вопросов, на который придется ответить - какие вершины двух треугольников считать парными* Ну тут никуда не деваться от перебора. *изменяется длина вектора* Как, ну вот КАК может изменяться ДЛИНА? Или непонятно, что центр координат есть тот самый центр (кстати, какой? впрочем, неважно...) треугольников.

Comment: Допустим есть два вектора (1;1) и (1;2) и если приравнивать производные к нулю то новые координаты вектора 2 буюут (1;1) следовательно длина вектора изменилась, либо я что то не то делаю

Comment: 1. Определите в условии и укажите в вопросе, что такое "центр треугольника". 2. Определите в условии и укажите в вопросе, что такое "вершины лежали максимально близко". Без этих двух уточнений, на вопрос дать однозначный ответ нельзя. Ну или сформулируйте задачу в более общем виде, если условие вы придумали сами ..

Comment: @S.Muller: Это у вас надо спрашивать, что можно, а что нельзя. Еще раз: сформулируйте вменяемый критерий оптимальности. Сумма расстояний? Среднее расстояние? Максимальное расстояние? Еще что-то? Без этого постановка задачи бессмысленна.

Comment: @AnT  В условии  говорится не об оптимальности, а о "максимально близко". А здесь вряд ли могут быть разночтения.

Comment: @Эникейщик что максимально ближе, 1+1+1 или 3+0+0 или 2+0,5+0,5 или 2+1+0 или еще бесконечное множество вариантов? По какому критерию выберете?

Comment: @Kromster Уравнение может иметь несколько решений. Ваш пример как раз такой случай.

Comment: @Kromster в случае двух векторов решение вроде бы единственное, в случае если рещенип не единственное (наверное, для двух треугольников такое возможно), просто взять сумму квадратов и там где полученное число будет меньше то и ответ. В вашем случае это 3, 9, 4.5, 5, следовательно ответ тот где сумма квадратов 3

Comment: Внесите это правкой в вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будем пользоваться полярными координатами. Зададим 2 треугольника парами значений в полярных координатах:

[image]

[image]

Угол поворота второго треугольника относительно первого: [image]

Так как у вас нет четкого условия про минимальное расстояние, возьмем сумму квадратов расстояний (визуально это должен быть наилучший вариант). Используя формулу для расстояния между 2 точками на полярных координатах получаем такие квадраты расстояний:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Мы должны найти минимум функции сумм этих 3 величин. В нас здесь много констант, что бы упростить формулу, положим:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

И тогда наша сумма квадратов расстояний примет вид:

[image]

Возьмем производную, что бы найти экстремумы функции:

[image]

Если расписать синус разницы, то получим:

[image]

Положим:

[image]

[image]

И получим:

[image]

Такое уравнение легко решить, если взять такой угол [image], что:

[image]

[image]

Тогда уравнение примет вид:

[image]

Такое легко решить. Дальше нужно повторить все это, смещая точки второго треугольника: сначала сместить на 1 (первая точка станет второй, вторая третьей и т. д.), потом на 2.

Comment: Извините, не особо понимаю для чего нужно вводить еще одно неизвестное (х), почему нельзя сразу найти угол фи через тангенс или котангенс фи? (Разделив либо на косинус, либо на синус). И еще не понял про смещение на 1, а потом на 2, не понимаю откуда эти цифры и каким образом смещать на один...

Comment: @S.Muller Все верно, вы должны взять арктангенс (или арксинус/косинус). Но нужно что бы совпали знаки, поэтому нельзя просто сказать, что x=arctan(...). Например, если тангенс получится 0, то это или 0 градусов или 180. Это разные решения. Что бы выбрать правильное, вам нужно посмотреть, какой косинус, если 1 - это 0, если -1 - это 180.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, попробую реализовать...